# node.js error : This socket is closed Node.js/gm library

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

am working on a project in Node.js with gm library,

every thing is going perfect but when the execution reaches this line

```
 gm(data).size(function (err, size) {
```

the execution throw an error

```
[Error: This socket is closed.]
```

i am not able to figure it out why this error occur ?

i google it with reference to gm but 0 success,

am confused whether this error is because of `gm library` or something else

Comment: I find it likely that there is another function event in your event loop that is causing this.  That being said, I would be curious what the contents of your "data" variable are. You haven't posted very much code.

Comment: no this is the function which cause this error , because i checked by placing console on above and below this function , it console out the above one but not the below , this function through the error

Comment: i also forget to mention that am using 'mysql-queues' lib for db transaction,

Comment: the data consist of the image link (path to image)